# Equivalent of wevtutil in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

`wevtutil` is a command in cmd for displaying Windows logs in different formats.

What is the equivalent cmdlet in Powershell?

Comment: It's usually not possible to map the old utilities to "a" Powershell command because the old utilities had to include every type of output format they wanted to provide.  With Powershell, the base command, such as Get-Eventlog, can get various objects, but then to get the output the way you want it you may have to pipe it to another command, or two, or three...

Comment: *Get-WinEvent* has superseded *Get-EventLog* In Vista+. Just type `gcm *Event* -CommandType cmdlet` to see all the relevant cmdlets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still use wevtutil sometimes in PowerShell... for instance, i use:

```
wevtutil el | ForEach {wevtutil cl "$_"}
```

to clear all of my event logs.

There are a number of Event management cmdlets in PowerShell including:

- Clear-EventLog
- Disable-VMEventing
- Enable-VMEventing
- Get-Event
- Get-EventLog
- Get-EventSubscriber
- Get-WinEvent
- Limit-EventLog
- New-Event
- New-EventLog
- New-WinEvent
- Register-CimIndicationEvent
- Register-EngineEvent
- Register-ObjectEvent
- Register-WmiEvent
- Remove-Event
- Remove-EventLog
- Show-EventLog
- Unregister-Event
- Wait-Event
- Write-EventLog

You can get a list of available cmdlets by using a command along the lines of:

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet -Name *Event*
```

If you need help on one of these specific cmdlets, you can use the get-help command like so:

```
get-help Write-EventLog
```

Hope this helps,